# Iterate through columns in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = rep(1, 15),
                  col2 = rep(2, 15),
                  col3 = rep(3, 15),
                  group = c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 5), rep("C", 5)))

for(col in c("col1", "col2", "col3")){
   filt.df <- df %>%
     filter(group == "A") %>%
     select(group, col)
     # do other things, like ggplotting
 }
```

> Error: All select() inputs must resolve to integer column positions.
>   The following do not:
>   *  col

How can I iterate through a specific vector of columns using `dplyr`? I know I would use something like `df[[col]]` in `base` R, but am unfamiliar with how to do it in `dplyr`.

Comment: So you want a list with group A & col1, group A & col2, group A & col3, group B & col1, etc...?

Comment: Yes. In my real data, `col1`, `col2`, and `col3` are difference vectors that I want to make different charts for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this should work. I use the select_() function

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(col1 = rep(1, 15),
                 col2 = rep(2, 15),
                 col3 = rep(3, 15),
                 group = c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 5), rep("C", 5)))

for(col in c("col1", "col2", "col3")){
  filt.df <- df %>%
    filter(group == "A") %>%
    select_(.dots = c('group', col))
  # do other things, like ggplotting
  print(filt.df)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`select_` and other underscore alternatives are now depreciated in dplyr. One should now use `select(group, .data[[col]])`. See the `programming` vignette in dplyr help for more.